# changing the position of main camera according to its current position in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am creating a 2d game where my camera position y axis has to be changed/decreased according to its current y position.

```
public void continuebut()
{
    campos = 0;
    campos = transform.position.y;

    if (campos <0)
    {

        campos += 4;//negative y position so the result will decrease the y position
        transform.Translate(0, campos, 0);
    }
    else 
    {

        campos -= 4;//positive y position so the result will decrease the y position
        transform.Translate(0, campos, 0);
    }

}
```

i expect the positive y position to be decreased but this code increase the y position of the camera instead of bringing down in y its going up. but it is not what i expected.i want the camera position y to go down when its a non negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

```
campos=0;
```

is pointless since it is immediately followed by:

```
campos=transform.position.x;
```

In fact, the compiler probably skips it completely and that line does not get in the final code.

About the rest of the code, you need to rethink what you are actually commanding to your app.
You first take your y axis position. Let's suppose

```
transform.position.y=5.0f;
```

So,

```
campos=5.0f;
```

Since

```
campos>0.0f
```

Your app does reduce campos

```
campos-=4;
```

So campos becomes 5-4=1.0f
Now, you do

```
campos.Traslate(0,1.0f,0);
```

So you are basically moving your object UP. 
What you might want to do instead is

```
transform.Translate(0,-4.0f,0);
```

However, consider that you probably would end up getting an oscillating object when it gets close to 0, oscillating every frame 4 units up and down.

Answer (score 1):

I may be off, but i think you're talking about this:

```
public void continuebut()
{
    campos = 0;
    campos = transform.position.y;


    if (campos >0)
    {
        // If camera position is positive
        // Decrease camera y position
        campos -= 4;//positive y position so the result will decrease the y position
        //Translate camera position
        transform.Translate(0, campos, 0);
    }
    else 
    {
        // If camera position if negative or zero
        // Increase camera y position
        campos += 4;//negative y position so the result will increase the y position
        //Translate camera position
        transform.Translate(0, campos, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually in that script the condition was <0 I accidentally wrote >0 . What you have suggested I already did but didn't work

Comment: Maybe you need to replace transform.Translate with transform.position? Or  specify Space relativeTo argument as Space.Self. What kind of result did you get?

Comment: Origin may be anywhere else.